# Problems with libpng and Mac OS X

Tags: macos, homebrew

I keep getting the same error while trying to run an app which uses opencv:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.8.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

I tried to update and upgrade Homebrew but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Install libpng?  http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that my app was linking to the wrong version of OpenCv. Uninstalling and then installing it again from source solved the problem.

Thanks for the help!